# Unexpected Error comparing directories in Win 7

Tags: batch-file

I need to compare for equality two directories that hold a large number of files (eg. `comp d1\*.* d2\*.*`).  A `for` loop comparing the files individually is far too slow.  I only care if all files exist and are equal; in other words, I only care about the `comp.exe` return code.

However when a file exists that begins with a period I get an unexpected error.  For example, if I do the following:

```
md d1
echo x >d1\.file
md d2
echo x >d2\.file
comp d1\*.* d2\*.*
```

it produces:

```
d1\.file      d2\*.*
Could not expand second file name so as to match first
```

Replacing `comp` with `fc` produces the identical result.  I have no idea why this is happening -- the directories should be entirely equal -- and wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: You see a file that begins with a period, I see a file with no name just an extension! What happens if you compare those two by name instead of wildcard, `comp "d1\.file" "d2\.file"`?

Comment: comp with the filenames specified works as I would expect:
`comp  d1\.file  d2\.file

Comparing d1\.file and d2\.file...
Files compare OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt window and run [comp /?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/comp) or [fc /?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc) and read the output short help. Or read the two referenced Microsoft help pages with examples from Microsoft's [command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands).

We have to clarify some terms to understand the problem.

The **name of a file** on Windows consists of two parts:

1. The **file name** being everything left to last `.` in **name of file**.
2. The **file extension** being last `.` and everything right to it in **name of file**.

Well, the last `.` is in real the separator between **file name** and **file extension**. Therefore the string after last `.` is in real the **file extension**. But the dot/point must be also belonging to either **file name** or **file extension** to build on simply concatenation of both parts the **name of file**. For that reason the last dot is added to **file extension**.

So on Windows a file with **name of file** being `.file` has an *empty* **file name** and `.file` as **file extension** which can be seen on running in a command prompt window:

```
@for %I in (.file) do @echo File name="%~nI" & echo File extension="%~xI"
```

The output is:

```
File name=""
File extension=".file"
```

On Unix/Linux there is no such definition of **name of file** consisting of two parts although many files on Unix/Linux have also **name.ext** syntax because this makes it easier for people to get an information about type of file (png, jpg, sh, txt, ...).

All Windows file systems support the attribute **hidden** to mark a file or directory as hidden. Unix/Linux file systems do not have such an attribute. On Unix/Linux a directory or file is interpreted as hidden when its name starts with `.`. For that reason a file like `.file` is interpreted on Unix/Linux as hidden file with name `file`. `.htaccess` is a very common hidden file on Linux web servers of which name is in real `htaccess` while the dot at begin marks this file as hidden on Unix/Linux.

Okay. So what is the problem here on comparing the directories `d1` and `d2` containing both only one file with `.file` as **name of file**?

The two files have no **file name**. But both compare commands need on usage of wildcards the **file name** parts to identify those two files from both directories to compare. That's how those two comparison commands on Windows are designed for comparing multiple files in two directories.

Working are:

```
comp d1\.file d2\.file
fc d1\.file d2\.file
```

But a comparison with wildcards does not work if one file in one of the two directories matching the wildcard pattern have an empty **file name**. The two console applications `comp.exe` and `fc.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\System32` fail in this special case to find the matching file in the other directory also having no **file name**, just a matching **file extension**.

The used command line `comp d1\*.* d2\*.*` could be also written as `comp d1\* d2\*` because Windows interprets `*.*` always like just `*`. This can be seen on running `dir *.*` which finds also folders and files not containing a `.` at all.

On using `comp d1\*.* d2\*.*` the console application **COMP** searches first for any file in directory `d1` and in this case finds the file `.file`. It splits the name of this file up into **file name** and **file extension**. The **file name** is an empty string with length 0.

**COMP** is written to search in other directory `d2` for a file with same **file name** as the found file in first directory has with the file extension specified on command line as second argument. In this case the specified file extension on command line is also `*` which means any file extension.

So **COMP** should search for *nothing*.* or more precisely search for `.*` in folder `d2` because the file with **name of file** `.file` has no **file name**.

What does `dir .*` output in comparison to `dir *` or `dir *.*`?

`dir .*` outputs just file and folder names starting with a dot while `dir *` and `dir *.*` output both all files and folders in current directory.

So **COMP** should work to find file `.file` in `d2`.

But if **COMP** finds a file with an empty **file name**, it does not even run this search in other directory and instead outputs the error message.

Interesting is that not working are in this special use case:

```
comp d1\*      d2\*
comp d1\*.*    d2\*.*
comp d1\.file  d2\*
comp d1\.file  d2\*.*
comp d1\.file  d2\*.file
```

But working are in this special use case:

```
comp d1\*      d2\.file
comp d1\*.*    d2\.file
comp d1\*.file d2\.file
```

This is (for me) a quite clear indication for a special use case not taken into account by the developers who wrote the code of **COMP** and **FC**. Users rate usually such a not correct handled use case by an application as **BUG**.

The simple solution to workaround this **bug** of **COMP** and **FC** is to use a different directory comparison tool like Beyond Compare, UltraCompare, etc. which can handle this special case correct.

A possible workaround could be temporarily renaming files starting with a dot by inserting `###` at begin, running the directory comparison, and renaming the files starting with `###` back to their original names.

```
@echo off
ren d1\.* ###.* 2>nul
ren d2\.* ###.* 2>nul
echo N | %SystemRoot%\System32\comp.exe d1\* d2\* >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 ( set "Result=different" ) else set "Result=identical"
echo Folders d1 and d2 are %Result%.
ren d1\###.* .* 2>nul
ren d2\###.* .* 2>nul
```

Of course this simple workaround solution does not work correct if there are files with `###` at begin of name of file already present in one of the two directories.

Comment: I did read the help text for `fc` and `comp` and saw nothing applicable to the question I posed.  I carefully read your response and can't find an explanation for this `comp` and `fc` quirk either  **The wildcard mask `*.*` should match a file with an extension but empty name.**  Please note it does match in the `comp` or `fc` command for the FIRST instance of ".file1" but (apparently) not the second.   Side note: A `dir *.*` will match and display a file named ".file1"  As far as I can tell your answer is restating the problem but not explaining why `comp` and `fc` behave in such a manner.

Comment: Well, I did not want to write __BUG__ as what is a bug and what is by design should be classified always by the producing company or developer(s) of an application and not by its users. However, I analyzed this issue more deeply with black box testing, described what I could see using additionally Process Monitor of Sysinternals and added a possible workaround for this very special use case with files in directory being interpreted as files with no __file name__.

Comment: By the way, in Unix/Linux a file beginning with a dot includes the dot in its name. For example the file `.htaccess` is *not* a hidden file named `htaccess`. It is a file whose filename is `.htaccess` inseparable from the dot. You can even have two files in the same directory called `.htaccess` and `htaccess` and they would be two completely separate and unrelated files.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Yes, I know that the dot at begin belongs to __name of file__ also on Unix/Linux. But nevertheless for users this dot at begin does not really matter. The file is the [hypertext access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file. The dot prefix in __name of file__ is just for getting this file by default not listed on standard directory listings on *nix systems. It has for the *nix users no meaning regarding to what the __name of file__ expresses about contents of this file.

Comment: @Mofi Thank you for the in-depth analysis.  Yes I also did not say **BUG** I called it a "quirk."  Quirks are to be expected.  Well there seems not to be a viable workaround -- temporary file renaming is fraught with danger; this comparison is a long process that can be interrupted.  Unfortunately empty filenames do exist in a Windows environment; for instance, the chrome browser creates them.  I was hoping to use built-in Windows command line tools for this task, but your suggestion of installing and using a different directory comparison tool seems necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, `fc` and `comp` have problems with filenames without name ("starting with a dot") *and* wildcard usage. There is no problem, if you don't use wildcards. This can be done with a simple `for` loop:

```
@echo off 
setlocal
for %%a in (d1\*) do (
  fc "d1\%%~nxa" "d2\%%~nxa" >nul 2>&1
  if errorlevel 1 set /a fail+=1
)
echo Failed: %fail%
if %fail% == 0 echo all ok.
```

(I recommend `fc`, because it doesn't ask for more files to compare; All output is discarded by `>nul 2>&1`)

Comment: I would recommend `fc /b` (compare binary rather than text) if you want a byte-for-byte comparison.

Comment: (BTW you have missing percents in: `if %fail% == 0`).  As I stated in the question a `for` solution is far too slow.  I tried your above code on identical `d1` and `d2` folders with 2,000 files; it took 37 seconds.  A `comp d1\* d2\*` took 1.5 seconds.  Also using `fc/b` has a fatal flaw -- comparing unequal gigabyte files will generate a gigabyte of lines of the form `004C4B3F: 00 01` greatly slowing it down.  I see no way to prevent this.  `comp` will only generate 10 lines of mismatch report.

Comment: And there is one more issue with this approach. If directory `d2` contains a file which directory `d1` does not have, but all files of directory `d1` exist in directory `d2` and are identical, `fail` is after the loop 0 although the directories are not identical. Of course this case with file(s) in directory `d2` not existing in `d1` could be also extra checked. For example a quick directory listing comparison before __FOR__ loop could be done to find out if the files lists of both directories are identical at all.

Comment: @Mofi That was how my original .BAT worked -- I performed a `dir  /s /b` listing just the directories, then another listing just the files.  I performed an `fc` on these outputs to insure the directory structures and file lists were identical.  Then I tried to continue by comparing the file contents one directory at a time, which is when I ran into the `comp` quirk with empty (leading period) filenames.